# Implementing generic class and multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, syntax

I have the following class definition:

```
public class SessionTreeManager<T> 
    : DataManager<T> where T : DataItem, IDeletable, IAnotherInterface
```

I only want T to be a DataItem and to implement the other two interfaces.  The compiler seems to think I want T to be any of the 3 and gives build errors as my T in the class above doesn't implement all 3 and this class cant find methods to override.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please give more details; show the code which fails to compile, and the error message. There's nothing wrong in your class declaration, so the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: The message states:  The type 'Session' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SessionTreeManager<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Session' to 'IDeletable'.    The compiler error is on the class th is implementing this as the T being passed in  'Session' does not implement all 3.  As I stated T should only be implementing the first item, DataItem.  The next ones should be implemented by SessionTreeManager itself

Comment: The definition of Session shouldn't matter, it implements DataItem and that is all it needs to do.  SessionTreeManager needs to implement the other interfaces.  The compiler seems to believe that 'Session' (T) should implement all 3

Comment: I think I don't understand correctly. Do want only DataItems to fit in that implement the interfaces?

Comment: That's actually not what I understood from your question. It's unclear at best. And yes, what you wrote constraints T to be a DataItem and to implement the two interfacs. Simply place your `where T: DataItem` at the very end of the line will fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have to do the following:

```
public class SessionTreeManager<T> 
    : DataManager<T>, IDeletable, IAnotherInterface 
    where T : DataItem {}
```

Which says, `SessionTreeManager` extends/implements `DataManager`, `IDeletable` and `IAnotherInterface` and the generic is constrained to `DataItem`.

You can also set the extends to `DataManager<DataItem>` as mentioned in the other comment, but then the parent methods will not be constrained to `class T` and will rather be constrained to its parent `DataItem`. This way all the methods of `SessionTreeManager` as well as its parent class `DataManager` will be constrained to the subclass of `DataItem` which is `class T`

Comment: this also works, similar to answer from Sievajet. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public class SessionTreeManager<T> : DataManager<DataItem>, IDeletable, IAnotherInterface
```